# Aligning img vertically inside List Item

Tags: html, css

Is there any way to align the images vertically in LIST ITEM using CSS only?

The I have a slider (slowed down) that needed to be aligned vertically in a 500px-height LI
The site is in `http://210.48.94.218/~printabl/design/portfolio/`.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your images are too heavy to load.

Comment: You're having errors in your script.  press F12 to check console.

Comment: I'm using soliloquy plugin for wordpress in loading the image. Are you sure.

@NathanLee: some of the images are PNGs but how can I make those images load in the middle rather than top?

Comment: For that, I need to see images getting loaded, but that is not happening in your case right now.

Comment: @NathanLee: okay i changed the interval already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your **list items** have a **fixed height**, you can use line-height combined with vertical-align: middle to do this.

Example:

```
ul li {
    display: block;
    height: 500px;
    line-height: 500px;
}

ul li img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[Working example here.](http://jsfiddle.net/kg8HG/1897/)

Answer (score 0):

This is a use case for Flexbox:

```
ul {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

(use vendor prefixes where necessary depending on your browser; see http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)

And then remove `height: 500px` from `.soliloquy-item`.